# Where should I process log events for logstash ? (Agent vs Server )

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

This might be a very generic and 'depends on your environment' type of question but I would like to know the best practice based on your experience on dealing with logstash and log aggregation in general.

So, I am trying to integrate logstash in our production environment and we have large number of log events (65K/minute) which will be collected in one central location. I have 10 VMs which are placed on different physical machines and they will all be sending the respective logs to a logstash server which is on different physical box. To do some analytic and clean up I am adding some more field to every log event (5 fields/event). The question is, where should I do the filtering and adding the fields to an event? on the logstash agents which are running on 10 VMs or on the server which will collect 650K messages every minute?

Even though I have allocated sufficient memory to the server (32GB) and it can process all those events, would it be "OK" to process these many number of events on the server or should I process them on client side with much less memory but bare the cost of having to send these events over a network which might cause network congestion.

Any help and/or suggestions/experiences are greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always found it easiest to have Logstash live on the same box as the data its processing. Right there, you can pre-process and massage the data and then ship it to ElasticSearch for storage and search.

If that's not possible, then it really does depend on your environment and situation. I would do it on your server in this case as it will be a single point to manage the configuration of the extra fields and it sounds like it has enough horsepower.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go the "server" way and run one Agent on said server. 65/minute should be easy for a powerful server. Two reasons mainly:

1. First, should you need to change any of the processing rules (GROK patterns, KV rules, etc), you would only need to do it on this one machine, restart the logstash process, and voila, done.
2. Secondly, since all the processing will be done on the server, you don't necessarily have to install Java and allocate those resources on the VMs. If those machines are doing other things, this could be a big win.

In production, I have all the app servers running [Logstash-Forwarder](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-forwarder) to forward all their raw logs onto a Logstash agent server that does all the collecting and processing of the logs. Haven't had any issues yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are two benefits to running a full logstash as your shipper:

- you can add a little load to each distrubuted machine for the
  processing, rather than needing a more powerful centralized machine
  to process all the information.
- you can analyze and limit the information being sent to the centralized machine (ignoring certain log entries, etc), thus saving
  network bandwidth.

The downsides of this are:

- you're running a JVM on each machine!
- you have to distribute your config to each machine when you make a change.

Running a JVM everywhere is not very attractive, so I forgo the benefits and run a lightweight shipper (logstash-forwarder) to send the logs to the centralized machine.

As for adding fields, doing it at the centralized machine would keep you from transmitting that extra information across the network.

10k events/sec is a decent load for logstash and elasticsearch to handle.

Good luck!